# Data is not inserting into mysql database using android application

Tags: java, android

**Java Code...!**

```
public void saveDB(View v)
{
    //BackgroundTask Class Execution

    name= ""+output1.getText().toString();
    batch_no= ""+output2.getText().toString();
    price= ""+output3.getText().toString();
    mfg_dt= ""+output4.getText().toString();
    exp_dt= ""+output5.getText().toString();

    insertintoDB();

    onBackPressed();
}

public void insertintoDB()
{
    //setting name value pairs
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    //Adding the variables inside the NameValuePairs

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("batch_no",batch_no));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",price));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mfg_dt",mfg_dt));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exp_dt",exp_dt));

    //Setting up the connection inside the try and catch block

    try
    {
       //Setting up the default http client
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://illusion.netau.net/android/saveData.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        //Getting the response
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //Setting up the entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        //Setting up the content inside the input stream reader
        is = entity.getContent();

       /* URL url=new URL("http://illusion.netau.net/android/saveData.php");
        urlConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();
        is=urlConnection.getInputStream();*/

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data Entered Successfully...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.e("Conn_Fine", "connection success ");
    }catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        Log.e("Client Protocol","Log_tag");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        Log.e("Log_tag","IOException");
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Access",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

This is my java code where i am saving data into mysql db using httpClient....!

-------------------- LOGCAT Message.---------------------------

```
04-12 20:56:57.473 2189-2189/com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@713eb3c time:19721431
04-12 20:57:01.734 2189-2189/com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample E/pass 1: connection success 
04-12 20:57:01.743 2189-2189/com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample time:19725701
04-12 20:57:01.763 2189-2189/com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample I/Choreographer: Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-12 20:57:02.057 2189-2189/com.example.fezimirza.layoutexample I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@1932a91 time:19726015
```

Comment: Google recommends processing DB calls on a separate thread from the UI - which looks like is your problem.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `Log.e` for a success message, but the logcat shown has no errors.

Comment: I am new on Android please can you suggest me any example...

Comment: what is the response from your server?

Comment: Connection with server is successfull..
No issues with that...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it!!!!!

```
public void saveDB(View v)
{




new insertintoDB().execute();
}  

class insertintoDB extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        /*
         * pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
         * pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..."); pDialog.show();
         */
    }

@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://illusion.netau.net/android/saveData.php");

        try {
             name= ""+output1.getText().toString();
             batch_no= ""+output2.getText().toString();
             price= ""+output3.getText().toString();
             mfg_dt= ""+output4.getText().toString();
             exp_dt= ""+output5.getText().toString();
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name",name));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("batch_no",batch_no));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price",price));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mfg_dt",mfg_dt));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("exp_dt",exp_dt));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
        return null;
    }

 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        /*
         * if (pDialog.isShowing()) { pDialog.dismiss();
         * Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Complete",
         * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
         */
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any code here that's responsible for writing to a database. It looks like you're making an API call to some API (that I'm guessing is responsible for writing to the database). If that's the case, then you should simply be checking to ensure that the API call is successful and was made using the correct `POST` body and if so, debug your API code to figure out why stuff isn't being written to your database correctly.

Answer (score 0):

1. As mentioned by zec and Nguyễn Trung Hiếu , server call should happens in secondary thread using AsyncTask . If you are new to android check this ..http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
2. The parameter which you send to server . Which format that your server accepts. That server side response could not reflect in android code. Check that php part of receiving the data.

Comment: Thanks to everybody who helped me in this issue...!
I have made the correction with the code by using AsyncTask, Now working correctly everything...!!!